# C:\Users\defaultu\.m2\repository\...plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5\maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom. (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: eclipse, maven

I converted my web project into maven using eclipse. I am getting following error in my pom.xml at line number one

C:\Users\defaultu.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5\maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom. (The system cannot find the path specified)

My pom.xml is as follows

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>AppName</groupId>
       <artifactId>FRC</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src</directory>
       <excludes>
         <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
       </excludes>
     </resource>
   </resources>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
   <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>
                                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                                </groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    maven-compiler-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[3.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
      </build> 

 </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

did u set Maven environment variables?
In command line `mvn -version` worked?

Comment: I am using maven inside my eclipse. Do I still need to set maven environment variables?

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified" so u must say to your system where is maven. And in first line of .pom should not be spaces.